# Monaco is pixelated in web pages

Tags: fonts, configuration, antialiasing

I installed Monaco font and it looks great in terminal:

> [image]

but it looks ugly in the browsers:

> [image]

How can I fix such a behavior? I would like to see the correct font in web pages too.

Comment: How are you getting it to show on web pages? Are you overriding the standard fonts?

Comment: @Oli The CSS says that. For example the very this textarea (when writting a comment) have this rule for `font-family`: `textarea { font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif }` I guess you noticed the `Monaco` font that is placed **before** `Lucida Console` or `monospace` that look ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

- First create a file in **.config/fontconfig/conf.d/** directory with **20-no-embedded.conf** name.
- Then put the below lines in the file to disable embedded bitmaps for all fonts.(If you don't want to disable for all fonts, but for some fonts, skip this to the next)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
  <fontconfig>
    <match target="font">
      <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
        <bool>false</bool>
      </edit>
    </match>
  </fontconfig>
  ```
- (Alternative) If you don't want to disable for all fonts, but only for a specific font, you should instead use these

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
  <fontconfig>
      <match target="font">
          <test qual="any" name="family">
             <string>Monaco</string>
          </test>
          <edit name="embeddedbitmap">
              <bool>false</bool>
          </edit>
      </match>
  </fontconfig>
  ```

  Below is a picture after successfully enabling anti-aliasing for Monaco. Have fun!

[image: Monaco problem solved image]

If you want to know more, check out [ArchLinux's fontconfig wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration) that helped me to solve this problem.

Comment: Seems like this is even better! *Below is a picture after successfully enabling anti-aliasing for Monaco. Have fun!* -- where is the screenshot?

Comment: The Code section is actually the screenshot!

Comment: Ah, right. But maybe you should include a window as well, because it's a little bit confusing. I thought it's a code block. :)

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I am so glad that this was fixed.

[Here](https://github.com/cstrap/monaco-font/commit/141f64f402ac4e804dbf4ffb96667753b1c08ab8) is the commit that fixed this: a new font.

It can be installed using the following command:

```
curl -kL https://raw.github.com/cstrap/monaco-font/master/install-font-ubuntu.sh | bash
```