# Terminal in Gnome 3: Disable audible bell, enable visual bell

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

For years, nay, decades (literally – two!), I have *visual bell* enabled in my terminals whenever possible, be it a humble XTerm or Gnome Terminal. Recently, after I switched from Unity to Gnome 3, I had an audible bell (over stereo speakers) in Gnome Terminal.

My searches up to now always seem to lead into the wrong direction: How to enable the audible bell or how to disable the whole thing completely. That’s not my intention. When at the prompt, when I press backspace too often or just before auto-completion, I want the terminal window to flicker, and I do not want to hear anything. Where is this setting hidden?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Disable audible bell and enable visual bell with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences audible-bell false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell true
```

and change the type of the visual bell if you don't need the fullscreen flash:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell-type frame-flash
```

---

Options for `visual-bell-type`:

- `fullscreen-flash` – causes a fullscreen white-black flash
- `frame-flash` – causes the titlebar of the application which sent the bell signal to flash

Comment: is this going to work on XFCE terminals?
Cause it tried and and it did not work.

Comment: This didn't work for me either.

Comment: If you use Vim note that it has its own bell setting. See `:help visualbell`. To enable Vim's visual feature, do: `:set visualbell`.

Comment: The above settings are visible in the GUI, under Settings / Universal Access / Visual Alerts.

Comment: For me, `frame-flash` flashes the whole window content black, not the title bar.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to realize that these settings only have an effect if the `Terminal bell` is enabled in gnome-terminal itself.

Comment: None of these seem to do anything unfortunately (Gnome Terminal 3.30.2)

Comment: flash flashes the content of the frame that caused the alert  rather than flashing the whole desktop content

Comment: please come up with a different solution.  this one no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences, Profiles, click on the active profile, click the Text tab, and uncheck "Terminal bell"

Comment: The GUI is misleading if you have the default profile which is called "unnamed".  You must not click on "Profile"  You must look under it and click on "unnamed".  Please include this in your answer.