# GNOME Terminal in 18.04: Visual bell only?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, terminal-bell

I want to disable the audible terminal bell, and enable the visual terminal bell. I followed the instructions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/620053/731225)

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences audible-bell
false

$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell
true

$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell-type
'frame-flash'
```

but I am getting **both** the audible and visual bells. Likewise, disabling the terminal bell under "Sound" in preferences disables **both** types.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the sound is coming from Ubuntu's alert system. In Ubuntu 18.04, you need to go Setting > Sound > Sound Effects > Alert Volume > Off.

I got this answer from:
[Turn off error sound on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030515/turn-off-error-sound-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

A work-around until you find the perfect solution is to replace the bell sound with no sound. On my system the alert sound is found in:

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg
```

To confirm it is the same sound you hear, use:

```
paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg
```

Then from this answer: [How to disable Alert volume from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25531/how-to-disable-alert-volume-from-the-command-line), try this:

```
sudo mv -v /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/*.ogg {*.disabled}
```

Note this disables all sounds. For just `bell.ogg` use

```
sudo mv -v /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg bell.ogg.disabled
```