# Make Ubuntu terminal not go Buuuumpppp

Tags: command-line, sound, gnome-terminal, indicator-sound

When we are in the terminal and we hit tab to complete the command line, and it can't complete all the way because there are multiple options, the terminal makes a "Bummmmpppp" noise.  Is there a way to switch this off?

Comment: You might also check `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts`, which is where the sounds are stored.  Maybe someone has been putting in little tricks?

Comment: @CharlesGreen You mean like here https://askubuntu.com/q/1057512/504066 ?

Comment: @PerlDuck I saw a post, I think here, long ago.  Someone had moved 'cat' and replaced with `echo meow` or something very similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like opening the terminal preferences and deselecting the `terminal bell` does the trick.

Comment: Took less time to find solution yourself than to type all this! Thx, always wondered how to do this.

Comment: Hehe - Yeah turned out the be remarkably simple - I was getting Buuuummmmppp shell shock!!  They should probably switch it off by default, only play it on the second try, or make a softer sound.

Comment: Sometimes I have the volume up and it actually scares me!

Comment: Yeah I realized how traumatized I was getting after accidentally having the headphones on max and hear BUMMMMMPPPPP!!!!.  I was like OH #%$#%@$ what did I just do????

Comment: Edit your Title lol, it's actually BUMMMMMPPPPP!!!!/DRRRRRIIIPPPPPPP!!!!

Comment: "How to keep Ubuntu from causing a nervous breakdown?"

Comment: It's especially bad when in the middle of some massive code refactoring and everything is going south and then on top of all that Ubuntu hits you with the BUMMMMMPPPPP!!!!/DRRRRRIIIPPPPPPP!!!!  I'll be in starbucks yelling at Ubuntu to shut up and people are like "What's this guys problem ..."